# Apache2 Vhost doesn't works with Symfony 2.8

Tags: php, apache, symfony, http-status-code-404, vhosts

I started symfony 2.8 project, and i have a problem with Apache2 vhosts.

When i try to get my admin home page, i have a 404 error.

that is my project vhost file (with 777 rights for tests) in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled directory:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName local.erdf.fr
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/erdf/web
    <Directory /var/www/erdf/web/>
    DirectoryIndex app_dev.php
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app_dev.php [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/errors.log
</VirtualHost>
```

(i restarted apache2 service after file creation)

I also thought that the problem could possibly come to misconfiguration in my routing config.

So that is my app/config/routing.yml:

```
admin:
    resource: "@AdminBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /admin
```

And my AdminBundle/Resources/routing.yml config:

```
admin_homepage:
    path:     /
    defaults: { _controller: AdminBundle:Default:index }
```

(i also tested with "pattern" argument instead of path).

In my local computer, i added in my /Etc/hosts:

```
192.168.1.20 local.erdf.fr
```

So, whend i try to access to url: local.erdf.fr/web/app_dev.php/admin, i have a 404 error.
(and if i just try local.erdf.fr/web/app_dev.php/ i have the apache2 default page in /var/www/html).

I hope I have been clear enough and thank you in advance for your help.

PS: I just created this server. Perhaps should I change a file in apache2 config to consider the vhosts ?

When i just use the url: local.erdf.fr, i have the /var/www/ racine:
[image]

EDIT: SOLVED

Ok so, thx to @Rufinus who put me on the road. indeed when i installed my apache server, i already added the

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

But i forget to add at the end of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf this:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
</ifModule>
```

Thank you all for your precious help :)
(and sry for my bad english)

Comment: What version apache is?

Comment: @felipsmartins it is Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)

Comment: So, in apache v2.4 you must change `Order Allow,Deny` by `Require all granted`. And of course, reload apache service.

Comment: ok done and restarted apache. But still not working . :/ @felipsmartins

Comment: `rewrite` module is enabled? as you have it in an if block you will not notice if it is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to access by local.erdf.fr/app_dev.php/ since your VHOST already aim to /web/ ?

Edit : 
Does the ip is right ?

Try to remove the trailing / in

```
<Directory /var/www/erdf/web/>
```

And remove the

```
DirectoryIndex app_dev.php
```

Comment: Hey thx for your help. nope it doesn't works, i have 404 error too

Comment: So, i added vhosts modifications but still not working.

Comment: Does the vhost activated ? sudo a2ensite example.com.conf

Comment: i crated the vhost directly in sites-enabled